# Cannot download Google workplace document like GoogleSheet to local using Google API Java

Tags: java, google-drive-api, google-sheets-api

As the Google Drive API document for exporting a Google Sheet stored on GG Drive: https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/manage-downloads
https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/ref-export-formats

I wrote following Java method in order download a GoogleSheet:

```
public void downloadFileFromDrive() throws Exception {
        String fileId = "1KVNuObZ4ACxKuOFTjf-SKkIgsDAr4L0x5hJzDz_uzhU";
        OutputStream outputStream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        serviceDrive().files().export(fileId, "application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet")
                .executeMediaAndDownloadTo(outputStream);
    }
```

I ran the program without error. My questions:

1. Where is the Excel file saved? The document didn't say about destination folder where file saved in local. I searched all files in my PC and didn't see any files I expected
2. Do I need to declare the path for destination folder for saving file from Drive?

Comment: Look like it's inside `outputStream`. Now you should write *that* to a file.

Comment: @FedericoklezCulloca I'd say the better option is to write directly to a `FileOutputStream` than writing it to a `ByteArrayOutputStream`.

Comment: Thanks so much @Mark Rotteveel. It worked for me with the same idea

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As what @Federico, it's already inside `outputStream`. But I'd recommend using `FileOutputStream` since you are outputting it to a file.

#### Sample:

```
OutputStream outputStream = new FileOutputStream(destinationFolder + fileName);
serviceDrive.files().export(fileId, "application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet").executeMediaAndDownloadTo(outputStream);
outputStream.flush();
outputStream.close();
```

#### Reference:

- [Java FileOutputStream](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/FileOutputStream.html)